# Редактирование XML-datagrid в WPF и паттерн MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Добрый день, извините сразу, перелазил 720 страниц различной инфы не нашел, суть вопроса как работать с XML файлами, редактирование, добавление , сохранение, удаление в WPF c учетом патерна MVVM, или что для начала нужно почитать чтоб разобраться в этой теме. Понял что мне нужен datagrid, считать в него могу(это легко) , а вот как дальше

```
string sampleXmlFile = @"C:\Users\umut.koseali\Desktop\students.xml";
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.ReadXml(sampleXmlFile);
DataView dataView = new DataView(dataSet.Tables[0]);
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dataView
```

Помогите плиз.

Это мой xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Students>
  <Student Id="0">
    <FirstName>Robert</FirstName>
    <Last>Jarman</Last>
    <Age>21</Age>
    <Gender>0</Gender>
  </Student>
  <Student Id="1">
    <FirstName>Leona</FirstName>
    <Last>Menders</Last>
    <Age>20</Age>
    <Gender>1</Gender>
  </Student>
  <Student Id="2">
    <FirstName>Helen</FirstName>
    <Last>Wilson</Last>
    <Age>21</Age>
    <Gender>1</Gender>
  </Student>
  <Student Id="3">
    <FirstName>John</FirstName>
    <Last>Smith</Last>
    <Age>22</Age>
    <Gender>0</Gender>
  </Student>
  <Student Id="4">
    <FirstName>Алексей</FirstName>
    <Last>Дроздов</Last>
    <Age>19</Age>
    <Gender>0</Gender>
  </Student>
  <Student Id="5">
    <FirstName>Вадим</FirstName>
    <Last>Халтурин</Last>
    <Age>21</Age>
    <Gender>0</Gender>
  </Student>
  <Student Id="6">
    <FirstName>Анна</FirstName>
    <Last>Говорухина</Last>
    <Age>20</Age>
    <Gender>1</Gender>
  </Student>
  <Student Id="7">
    <FirstName>Александр</FirstName>
    <Last>Иванов</Last>
    <Age>20</Age>
    <Gender>0</Gender>
  </Student>
</Students>
```

Как правильно вывести их в редактируемый список, с возможностью сохранения, добавления, редактирования информации?

Comment: Вы идете неправильным путем, вам нужна строго типизированная коллекция

Comment: то есть ваш тип будет примерно таким - `type Student = {ID : int; FirstName : string; Last : string; Age : int; Gender : bool }`

Comment: (заранее извините, что пишу на F#, просто более лаконично выглядит), но тут главное принцип. Класс в C# будет аналогичным, только будет занимать больше строчек для описания

Comment: следующий щаг - разбор и запись в xml, можно использовать сериализацию, а можно парсить через Linq2XML. У вас простой xml, я бы выбрал второй способ

Comment: подходит ли вам `DataGrid` зависит от того, в каком виде вы хотите отображать информацию,

Comment: Допустим тип я создам, можете более подробно про разбор и запись в xml, может есть ссылки где подробное описание ситуации на примере разбора другого кода?

Comment: давайте я сейчас напишу ответ, просто подождите несколько минут

Comment: у меня нет сейчас возможности проверить код, но я дополню его и исправлю если есть недочеты когда появиться время.

Comment: ...что конкретно у вас не получается?

Comment: я заметил, что вы отметили мой ответ, у вас получилось разобраться с дальнейшим самостоятельно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю отойти от `DataTable`, а использовать строго типизированные коллекции. Тогда порядок действий будет примерно следующим:

1.
Определить базовый класс Student

```
public class Student
{
public int ID { get; set; }
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string Last { get; set; }
public int Age { get; set; }
public bool Gender { get; set; }
}
```

2.
Определить класс для чтения

```
public static class XmlReader
    {
        public static IEnumerable<Student> readStudents(string path)
        {
            var xd = XDocument.Load(path);

            foreach (var xe in xd.Root.Elements("Student"))
            {
                var id = (int)xe.Attribute("Id");
                var firstName = (string)xe.Element("FirstName");
                var lastName = (string)xe.Element("Last");
                var age = (int)xe.Element("Age");
                var gender = (string)xe.Element("Gender") != "0";
                yield return new Student
                {
                    ID = id,
                    Age = age,
                    FirstName = firstName,
                    Last = lastName,
                    Gender = gender
                };

            }

        }
}
```

3.
Считать

```
var Data = XmlReader.readStudents(pathToFile).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

Ещё один вариант, с более жёсткой проверкой:

```
public class Student
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Last { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public bool Gender { get; set; }
}

public class Students
{
    [XmlElement("Student")]
    public List<Student> List { get; set; }
}
```

При этом код для чтения получается совсем простой:

```
IEnumerable<Student> ReadStudents(string path)
{
    using (var file = File.OpenRead(path))
        return ((Students)new XmlSerializer(typeof(Students)).Deserialize(file)).List;
}
```

Comment: Таким образом ID не десериализуются, например: они тут представлены как атрибуты, а не как дочерние элементы.

Comment: @DukeSpontaneous: У меня в тестовом примере вроде десериализовалось. Но для сериализации, наверное, нужно прописать `[XmlAttribute]`.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите использовать DataSet и DataGrid для редактирования данных в XML-источнике, то можете через DataSet и сохранить их

```
var sampleXmlFile = @"C:\Users\umut.koseali\Desktop\students.xml";
var stream = new FileStream(sampleXmlFile, FileMode.Open);
dataSet.WriteXml(stream, XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema);
stream.Close();
```