# ComboBox из XML-файла.

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Есть Xml-файл с таким содержимым:

```
<Student Id="0">
<FirstName>Robert</FirstName>
<Last>Jarman</Last>
<Age>21</Age>
<Gender>0</Gender>
```

```
<Student Id="1">
<FirstName>Leona</FirstName>
<Last>Menders</Last>
<Age>20</Age>
<Gender>1</Gender>
```

И так еще много студентов

Задачей является вывести все значения в ComboBox, или любые подходящие поля.
Прочитать смог таким образом: XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
А как их впихнуть в разные поля Combobox? 
Спасибо =)

Comment: Шаблон элемента переопределите

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/707596/wpf-Выбор-элемента-для-отображения/707883#707883

Comment: где-то я уже видел такой `xml` - файл =)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/707339/Редактирование-xml-datagrid-в-wpf-и-паттерн-mvvm/

Comment: Я взял его из Вашего примера :) Очень похожее задание у меня=)

Answer (score 1):

Хоть я в `XML` и не спец, но давайте попробуем так:

- Загрузим наш файл в строку: `var xmlStr = File.ReadAllText("temp.xml");`.
- Загрузим в `XElement` нашу строку: `var str = XElement.Parse(xmlStr);`
- Хм, а что же дальше? А дальше давайте создадим небольшой список, который будет в себе иметь всех студентов: `var students = str.Elements("Student");`
- Отлично, есть студенты, в удобном списке. Давайте пройдемся по ним, хм, циклом, но перед этим создадим необходимый элемент, в который мы будем добавлять наших студентиков, пусть будет `ComboBox`. В `Xaml`: `<ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox1" />`
- Отлично, теперь дело цикла!:

> ```
> foreach (var student in students)
> {
>     var id = student.FirstAttribute.Value;
>     var FirstName = student.Element("FirstName")?.Value;
>     var Last = student.Element("Last")?.Value;
>     var Age = student.Element("Age")?.Value;
>     var Gender = student.Element("Gender")?.Value == "0" ? "Дядя" : "Тетя";
>     ComboBox1.Items.Add($"[{id}] {FirstName} {Last} это {Gender} и за плечами {Age} г. ");
> }
> ```
>
> p.s. Не форматировался код без цитаты, если кто сможет, уберите ее.

Что мы тут видим? Хм, а нечего сверх сложного, просто у каждого объекта, который найдется для нашего цикла, мы отберем необходимые нам параметры, дальше мы их попросту добавим в наш `ComboBox1`.

Answer (score 1):

Вы делаете как-то слишком вручную. Выучите MVVM на досуге!
Имея класс `Student` из [этого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/707339/10105), проблема решается совсем просто.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Students}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Student}">
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="{Binding FirstName, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                <Run Text="{Binding Last, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                <!-- и так далее -->
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```